# How did Lo'ak learn the language of the Tulkun?

Tags: languages, communication, avatar-the-way-of-water

At one point during the movie, Jake Sully's son Lo'ak is abandoned (by Na'vi of the Metkayina clan) in the middle of a sea predator's territory. Lo'ak is saved from the predator by Payakan, a member of a sentient, intelligent whale-like species called Tulkun.

Lo'ak was not allowed to be in that location in the first place, and when he returns to the Metkayina village, he is chastised for being there.  Later on Lo'ak returned multiple times in secret to interact with Payakan (who is also an outcast of his/her species, and is despised/disliked by the Metkayina due to a perceived previous behavior of Payakan).

During these interactions, Lo'ak talks to Payakan with a combination of Na'vi language and the Metkayina clan sign language (of which Payakan fully understands).  Payakan in return communicates with Lo'ak with a whale-song like language, which Lo'ak *seems* to understand.

Given that Lo'ak is doing all of this in secret, how does he learn and understand the language of Payakan?  Or is he just doing the equivalent of nodding and smiling when Payakan talks?

Comment: Possibly the languages are similar enough. You might not speak French, but there are enough words that are similar to English that you could muddle your way through a basic conversation

Comment: @Valorum Whale song is in no way something like Na'vi.  Unless of course you take the position of [Dory speaking whale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJGeeryk0Eo) in Finding Nemo

Comment: Well, as Jake Sully's son, he presumably has inherited his father's talent for being inexplicably better at almost any activity than people from a culture that does it from childhood.

Comment: @Adamant Trust me, I saw that [plot point](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LedByTheOutsider) from mile a way /s  It